# Javascript | 'element.style.display' status check doesn't work in 'if gate'?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick, display

I want to make a button that changes div display mode and changes innerHTML of button on-click.

Display of content2 is initially set to 'none'.

My code doesn't currently change anything.

Thanks for the help.

Javascript

```
let button2 = document.getElementById('more-button-2');
let content2 = document.getElementById('more2');

   button2.onclick = function() {
        if (content2.style.display === 'none') {
            content2.style.display = 'block'; 
            button2.innerHTML = 'See less'; 
        } else if (content2.style.display === 'block') {
            content2.style.display = 'none'; 
            button2.innerHTML = 'See more' 
        } 
    };
```

HTML

```
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='column-content'>
            <h2>Two</h2>
            <p>Explanation.</p>
            <div class='more-button' id='more-button-2'>See more</div>
            <p id='more2'>More</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

As Pointy commented, the error was in my style only checking html defined styles.

I have edited the code to check buttons innerHTML and it now works. Probably not best practice though...

```
button2.onclick = function() {
    if (button2.innerHTML === 'See more') {
        content2.style.display = 'block';
        button2.innerHTML = 'See less';
    } else if (button2.innerHTML === 'See less') {
        content2.style.display = 'none';
        button2.innerHTML = 'See more'
    } 
};
```

Comment: The `style` object only contains style information actually set directly on HTML elements. Styles implied by CSS rules are not visible that way; you have to use `getComputedStyle()`. It's much simpler to add/remove classes to make code like that work.

Comment: Thanks you were correct. I have swapped the if gate to check the status of the buttons innerHTML and it now works. 

Post is updated. 

I will have to do some research in exactly how the style & get computedstyle commands work. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Incidentally, although this doesn't answer your specific question, a more idiomatic way of handling this might be to change some parent class and then allow all children to update their styles in CSS based on being inside the new class, rather than imperatively with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.stlye` doesnot have `display` property until its set to an element by using `Element.style.display = '...'` or in `html`. To get the exact value of `display` use `getComputedStyle`. And also use ternary operators instead of `if-else`

```js
let button2 = document.getElementById('more-button-2');
let content2 = document.getElementById('more2');

button2.onclick = function() {
  let {display} = window.getComputedStyle(content2);
  content2.style.display = display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  button2.innerHTML = button2.innerHTML === 'See More' ? 'Show Less' : 'See More'
};
```

```html
<div class='column'>
        <div class='column-content'>
            <h2>Two</h2>
            <p>Explanation.</p>
            <div class='more-button' id='more-button-2'>See more</div>
            <p id='more2'>More</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```